# Save JSON object as entity with associations using cakePHP 3

Tags: javascript, php, json, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I have a JSON object that I need to `post` & save it using cakePHP 3.

First I have 4 tables as in this image [image: TABLES]

Let's say a supplier buys some products, so I need to fill a `purchase` record and the association table `products_purchases`, which will contain all the records of products bought during that one `purchase`.

I'll be using some JavaScript to dynamically generate some fields to be able to fill multiple `products` with quantities, prices.. during that `purchase`, and then store all the data in a `JSON object`.

So in the `add.ctp` view of `purchase`, I'll have this `JSON object` for exmaple :

```
$data = {
    "reference": "V656413",
    "supplier_id": 31,
    "payment_id": 5,
    "products_purchases": [
        {
            "product_id": 5566,
            "purchase_id" 999,
            "quantity": 4,
            "price": 899
        },
        {
            "product_id": 7865,
            "purchase_id" 999,
            "quantity": 6,
            "price": 54
        },{
            "product_id": 434,
            "purchase_id" 999,
            "quantity": 8,
            "price": 22
        },
    ]
}
```

How can I `POST` this object using the `form` in the `add.ctp` file, and how can I handle it and save it as an entity with its associations in the `PurchasesController`?

The `add` method in the controller for now is as follow :

```
public function add()
    {
        $purchase = $this->Purchases->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $purchase = $this->Purchases->patchEntity($purchase, $this->request->data);


            if ($this->Purchases->save($purchase)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The purchase has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The purchase could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set('_serialize', ['purchase']);
    }
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You have to manage proper associations with your models. visit below link where you can see how to save data with associations.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html

Comment: I don't see how can I post and save JSON like that.

Comment: You need to decode the json data then submit on save function.